# Using Wordpress database for another kind of website

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and I want to make it into a mobile version. I detect the user agent and redirect the client to m.mydoamin.com. I've developed some PHP code in m.mydomain.com to show the data.
I have taken a look on Worldpress database, seem not easy to do this. Any ideal for me to do this ?

Comment: What do you want to with the Wordpress database? What kind of conversion?

Comment: Check out the [JSON API plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/). This will allow you to retrieve all of the data.

Comment: For example in my Wordpress I have articles, I want to show articles follow category.

Comment: Hi ssergei, it look like, on my mobile website, I have to develop WS, call data from Wordpress

Comment: Could you show us an example of this "some PHP code"? Are you not even attempting to run WordPress in the `m.domain.com` domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a theme for `Mobile Website` and change accordingly when user agent is `Mobile`. So it will use one `Database`.

Pseudo code:

```
If(userAgent == "mobile"){
$theme = "mobile";
}else{
$theme = "Desktop";
}
```